# facebook graph api /me/achievements returns unexpected results (empty data arrays with low limits)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 5 test achievements in my app. first,second,third,first_login,recurring_login. After a specific action an achievement is unlocked. The recurring_login achievement gets deleted and re-added every subsequent login after first_login. I do this to log the players last login to be able to use this information in their friends apps.

When I use the graph_api and collect me/achievements I have 2 problems:

1: when I use the graph-api-explorer scope I can see all my achievements
when I use the app scope I can not see the recurring_login achievement (I have seen it here some time ago, but it no longer apears).

2: when I search for me/achievements in graph-api-explorer scope I getthe recurring_login achievement when using limit=1 to limit=145
I get 2 achievents when using limit=146, 3 with 147 up to 5 at 149
When using app scope I get 0 achievements up to limit=147, 1 at 148 up to 4 at 151. recurring_login is never shown.

note recurring_login is correctly owned by app_scope as checked with application_id in graph-api-explorer scope searches.

It seems that perhaps the achievement is incorrectly removed and not overridden, but I have no clue how to find this out. Can someone solve this mystery?

Edit:

If i try to delete recurring_login in app scope (cannot be done in explorer scope) I get the following message:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "(#3404) User does not have requested achievement", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3404
    }
}
```

When I try to post it in stead (just change delete to post with exact same achievement=url) I get:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "(#3501) User has already earned this achievement.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3501
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Confirmed bug by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1364780566996794), given a low priority it probably wont be fixed soon.